# Sql query result if no records found

Tags: sql

what will be the output of the below given query, if no matching records are found

```
select avg(salary) from employee where dept='sales'
```

Will it return 0 or null ?

Comment: Might be worth trying :)

Comment: It may vary based on RDBMS (not specified).  Try it and find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns null: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg

Comment: Ok I have gone through the docs and it mentions over there that if there are no matching rows then it would give NULL. But what if there are matching rows and the salary column contains NULL value ??
Will it ignore the NULL value and return 0 in this case ??

Comment: Yes I think it will ignore null value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg).

It returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Easy test in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int)
INSERT INTO @T
SELECT NULL

SELECT AVG(id) FROM @T
```

Returns `NULL`

Answer (score -1):

By default in MySQL and i'm pretty sure it is too in MSSQL, all aggregation functions return NULL if no data or if ANY OF THE DATA IS NULL, you cannot compute an aggregation on missing data.

Comment: -1 This is wrong. Rows that are `NULL` are ignored.; also some aggregations functions (eg: `COUNT()`) will return 0 if no matching rows are found.

Comment: Sorry about that, i mixed up expressions and agregations... If you put NULLS in for example SELECT 1+NULL it returns null. I was confused :D